# Shapefile/ArcInfo to SVG? Preferably in Python

Tags: python, svg, maps, geospatial, shapefile

I'm interested in taking [these census cartographic files](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/z52000.html) and converting them into SVG files. So far I've found this [shptosvg Perl script](https://github.com/kbh3rd/shptosvg), but I'd really prefer to do any coding or data wrangling in Python.

Also, I know [shpUtils.py](http://indiemaps.com/blog/2008/03/easy-shapefile-loading-in-python/) can be used for parsing .shp files in Python, but I'm unaware how to take that output and create SVG paths.

Anyways, I'd definitely be interested in any advice you guys have or modules you know of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Late response, but here is exactly what you want, in Python with a wonderful API:

https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py

As comments have noted it was previously available at https://github.com/svgmap/svgmap.py

Answer (score 3):

The svgmap link was broken for me on github, but [kartograph.py](https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.py) works for ESRI shp. files

Answer (score 0):

Not python, but you may be interested in these links:

http://egb13.net/2009/07/shapefile-to-svg-translator-project/

http://www.carto.net/svg/utils/shp2svg/